# Lotus Script getting HTML Code as Text from a .htm File

Tags: html, lotusscript

Im still learnig lotusscript and I ran over a problem:
I have to extract the html-code from a .htm file but i have no clue how to do that.. 
Does someone have some advice?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Is the HTML file local to where the Lotusscript agent is executed, or is it a remote URL you will retrieve the HTML source from?

If the former, look up file operations in the online help. Not any different than in any other programming language.

If the latter, it depends on the operating system for where the Lotusscript agent is executed. If that is Windows 32-bit or 64-but, you can use the Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP COM object to retrieve the page source. I wrote a class for this years ago, you can find it at http://blog.texasswede.com/lotusscript-code-html-retrieval-class/